# How to know that the script should exit when exit comes within a job?

Tags: powershell

I have a script which starts a job `Start-Job` which monitors a process. Whenever this process dies, the script will automatically restart the process, and then restart the script.

If the script can't restart the process it will send an e-mail and should exit PowerShell completely, to avoid the restart of the script. I did this by just exiting inside the job, but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I tell my script to not restart, if the process could not be restarted?

Here's my code:

```
$sb = {
    while ((Get-Process LogikWebserver).Responding) { sleep -m 50 }
    if (!(Get-Process LogikWebserver).Responding) {
        #restart process
        try {
            Start-Process "$processpath\LogikWebserver.exe" -EA Stop
            sleep -s 2
            if (Get-Process LogikWebserver -EA Stop) {
                Send-MailMessage
            }
        } catch { 
            Send-MailMessage
            <# With this exit I want to tell the script to exit completely #>
            exit
        }
    }
}

# start and get job
Start-Job -Name LogikWebserverWatch -ScriptBlock $sb
Wait-Job -Name LogikWebserverWatch
Get-Job -Name LogikWebserverWatch | Remove-Job -Force

# restart script
$skript = "{0}\{1}" -f $PSScriptRoot, "Watch-LogikWebserver.ps1"
& $skript
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't catch exceptions inside the scriptblock. Receive the job output and catch exceptions there. Also, use an infinite loop for re-running the job rather than re-running the script.

```
$sb = {
    while ((Get-Process LogikWebserver).Responding) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
    }

    # restart process (at this point .Responding was already false, thus no
    # point in checking again)
    Start-Process "$processpath\LogikWebserver.exe" -ErrorAction Stop
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    if (Get-Process LogikWebserver -ErrorAction Stop) {
        Send-MailMessage
    }
}

while ($true) {
    # start and get job
    try {
        Start-Job -Name LogikWebserverWatch -ScriptBlock $sb |
            Wait-Job |
            Receive-Job -ErrorAction Stop
    } catch { 
        Send-MailMessage
        exit
    } finally {
        Get-Job -Name LogikWebserverWatch | Remove-Job -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So if anything would throw an error inside the job, `Receive-Job` throws an error too?

Comment: With `-ErrorAction Stop`.